# Has no method splice issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular js application where I'm trying to have a page that lists all of the products. It returns from a url that gives me:

```
{
  "products": [
  {
     "id":14,
     "name":"Test",
     "tags":[]
  }]
}
```

I have a partial that looks like:

```
<li ng-repeat="product in products.products | filter:searchProducts">
  <a>{{product.name}}</a>
  <a ng-click="deleteProduct(product.id, $index)">Delete</a>
</li>
```

and a controller that looks like:

```
app.controller('ProductsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Api', function($scope, Api) {
   $scope.products = Api.Product.query();

   //Delete Product
   $scope.deleteProduct = function(productId, idx) {
        Api.Product.remove({productId: productId});
        $scope.products.splice(idx, 1);
   };

}]);
```

and the Api Factory looks like:

```
app.factory('Api', ['$resource', function($resource) {
   return {
       Product: $resource('/api/products/:productId', {productId: '@productId'}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }}),
       Item:  $resource('/api/items/:itemId', {itemId: '@itemId'})
   };
}]);
```

When I click on the Delete link, it deletes the product from the backend, but it says:

```
TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'splice'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `$scope.products.products.splice()`. This is because you are assigning the resource object to `$scope.products`, which contains the array at the child products key.